# Upper bound series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If I want to prove that the series $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{n^3}{2^n}$ converges.
I know we can prove it by the root test, but there is a way to find an upper bound series?

Comment: HINT: For $n\geq 23, 2^n>n^5$.

Comment: What is intuition to know if you have $2^n > n^a$ for which number is $n$ greater than. (when you say for $n>...$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show by induction on $n$ that $n^3\le 2^{n/2}$ for $n\ge 30$. Then for $n\ge 30$ you have

$$\frac{n^3}{2^n}=\frac{n^3}{2^{n/2}}\cdot\frac1{2^{n/2}}\le\frac1{2^{n/2}}\,.$$

And $\sqrt2>1$, so

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac1{2^{n/2}}=\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)^n$$

converges.

Comment: Hi professor Scott, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3998448/about-the-definition-of-cartesian-product), please?

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

If $ |x|<1$ then

$$1+x+x^2+...=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}=F(x)$$

$$F'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

$$G(x)=xF'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n$$

$$G'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2x^{n-1}$$

So,

$$H(x)=xG'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2x^n$$
and

$$H'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^3x^{n-1}$$

Take now $ x=\frac 12$ and compute $ xH'(x)$.